# non constant acceleration problem

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics, kinematics

> The acceleration of an arrow from a bow falls from $6000m/s^2$ to zero when it leaves the bow after travelling a distance $x=0.75m$. Assuming that this acceleration can be expressed by the linear equation $a=6000[1-(4x/3)] m/s^2$ determine the speed of the arrow when it leaves the bow.
>
> How long does it take for the arrow to leave the bow?

to answer the first part of the question

$v dv = a dx$

$\int_U^V{v}$ dv = $\int_0^x{6000(1-4x/3)}$ dx

$\frac{(V^2 - U^2)}{2}$ = $2000(3x-2x^2)$

$V^2 = 4000(3x-2x^2) + U^2$

$V = \sqrt{4000(3x-2x^2) +U^2}$

substitute $x= 0.75$ and $U=0$ giving,

$$v=67.1 m/s$$

For the second part of the question I have got this far

$v=\frac{dx}{dt}$

$dt = \frac{1}{v} dx$

$\int_0^T{dt} =\int_0^x \frac{1}{v} dx$

$T = \int_0^x \frac{1}{\sqrt{4000(3x-2x^2) +U^2}} dx$

this integral is nasty, giving a complex solution but works out when I solve it giving the correct answer of $$t=0.0176s$$
Can anyone see a more efficient method for solving this problem? Is there a substitution I could use to make the integral easier? or am I missing an aspect of this question.

Comment: The force is proportional to the distance - sounds like a simple harmonic motion situation.

Comment: What is the value of $U$? I agree with M.Enns, its a shifted SHM sort of thing, can be solved by solving the 2nd order differential equation, but the way he is doing it , the integral has a singular point at $x=0$, for $U=0$.

Comment: Value of U is zero

Comment: Okay, then the integral has a singular point at $x=0$ and $x=3/2$ so you need to do the integration carefully.

Comment: Possible duplicate by OP: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/251991/2451

Comment: I don't think this question is 'off topic.'  The questioner has clearly made the effort to solve the problem, and rightly suspects that he has overlooked a simpler method of solution.  The insight proposed by M.Enns and implemented by John Rennie is instructive.  So I think the question and its solution have value to the wider community, not only to the questioner.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the setup described in the equation:

[image: Setup 1]

The acceleration is defined in terms os the displacement of the bow $x$ by:

$$ a = 6000 \left(1 - \tfrac{4}{3}x\right) \tag{1} $$

So initially $x=0$ and when we substitute this into equation (1) we get $a = 6000 \text{ms}^{-2}$. When the arrow leaves the bow so $x=\tfrac{3}{4}$ and we get $a=0$. So far so good.

But suppose we choose a different definition for the variable $x$ as shown below:

[image: Setup 2]

So now $x$ starts at $\tfrac{3}{4}$m and when the arrow leaves the bow $x=0$. If we define $x$ this way then the equation for the acceleration becomes:

$$ a = -8000x \tag{2} $$

let's just check this: at the start $x = \tfrac{3}{4}$m and putting this into equation (2) gives $a = 6000 \text{ms}^{-2}$. When the arrow leaves the bow $x=0$ and equation (2) gives $a=0$.

So equation (2) gives us the acceleration with our redefined meaning for $x$. But equation (2) is just the equation of motion for a simple harmonic oscillator:

$$ \frac{d^2x}{dt^2} = -kx $$

So the motion of the arrow is going to be given by an equation:

$$ x = \tfrac{3}{4}\cos\left(2\pi \frac{t}{\tau}\right) $$

where you can calculate the period $\tau$ by solving equation (2).

Comment: Thanks this is perfect. Helped me understand this much more efficient method. To clarify would the period in this case be 4t where t is the time taken for the arrow to leave the bow? It's conceptually difficult to think of as a bow string would not continue past the zero reference for x. cheers

Comment: @MurrayMackenzie: yes, divide the period by four to get the time from releasing the string to the arrow leaving the bow.